# Truncating a table in HBase did not free up space for HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hbase, ambari

I was having problems with HBase and HDFS, as I understood HBase runs on top of HDFS and thus I assumed it used HDFS to store its data. The problem was that HDFS was close to its maximum space utilization and it and HBase were constantly crashing.

Here is a picture of the monitoring tool Ambari in the HDFS tab:
[image]

For a reasonable amount of time I wasn't even able to run normal HBase shell comands such as list and scan, so I couldn't even try to delete some data from the tables. However, when I did manage to restart HBase, which is running in a single node, I truncated the table which was using that biggest amount of space and when I checked through the du (disk usage) command, the hdfs directory was even bigger. And the HDFS Space Utilization was still very high. How can I free up space in the Hadoop Distributed File System if not by removing entries from HBase? Removing random directories in the HDFS manually feels very sloppy and I would prefer not to do that. Should I increase HDFS reserved space? Should I decrease replication? Should I force a compaction?

Comment: Do you have any table snapshots? If so, the data might be held by the snapshots.

Comment: @shay__ We actually fixed the issue by increasing the disk space of the VM that was running HBase and HDFS. Not sure if it's an answer worthy solution though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increasing disk space for the VM that was running HBase and HDFS substantially reduced HDFS storage usage and it was enough for what I needed.

Just make sure you are expanding the partition where HDFS actually resides in.